# Template doesn't exist

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I am trying to learn it by building a project. I wanna replace the django's localhost hompage with my homepage. But, I couldn't find **views.py** in main project directory.Why? By the way, I made a new **'views.py'** and also created a templates folder and put index.html in another directory inside templates named **englishexchange**.  Below is the project structure.
**englishexchange/ manage.py and exnglishexchange/ views.py,urls.py and templates/englishexchange/index.html**

***englishexchange/url.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

***englishexchange/views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request): 
    return render(request, 'englishexchange/index.html')
```

and I put my templates directory in main **project directory englishexchange**.

I know I can do that by making another app and maping the url to nothing like **' '**. But I want them to have different home page than the main's static home page.

The error I am getting is like

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Sujeet Agrahari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\englishexchange\index.html (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Sujeet Agrahari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\englishexchange\index.html (Source does not exist)

I believe it's trying to find the templates in its default directory which is admin. How can I change this behavior so that it gets the templates from mian project directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*But, I couldn't find views.py in main project directory.Why?*

Django encourages you to make apps for almost anything you do. So there is no views.py in the main project directory.

Regarding template rendering be sure to add:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
```

in 'DIR' as stated in an answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your views.py file is inside the app folder you made , and templates folder inside the project folder not your app folder , for changing current home page , just add
 `path('home/', views.index , name = 'index'),`
You can replace home with any thing you want your home page url to be.

Comment: If there is another folder inside template directory for ex.`xyz` i.e the file location become `templates/xyz/index.html` , you should `return render(request , 'xyz/index.html')`

Comment: I haven't made an app yet. It's the main project directory. **englishexchange/ manage.py and exnglishexchange/ views.py,urls.py and templates/englishexchange/index.html**

Comment: First of all , if u havent made an app , views.py wont appear. Make a app typing `python manage.py startapp englishexchange` in terminal in project directory

Comment: all the files like views.py , models.py will automatically appear in the app folder and you dont have to make them manually

Comment: As I mentioned I can do that but that way every app will have its own home page, I just want a static homepage for the main project and separate homepage for each app if required.

Comment: Just add `from django.urls import include` and make a separate urls.py in app folder and then you can define urls separately for every app you want.In main urls.py that is present in project directory , just add `path(' ' , include("<app_name>.urls"))`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add this in your settings file

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},

]
```

where you can change the 'templates' in `DIRS` to any folder you want to keep your template files to.

Comment: Rather than making two answers, you should delete this one and append the content of this answer to your other answer. :)

Comment: I did those changes in DIRS, but that way I can only change the last directory in which it's looking for index.html. That doesn't change the base directory.

Comment: @ruddra , you are a certified django developer , can you tell me the source you learnt django